# Rijndael key expansion

Tags: groovy, aes

I am writing Rijndael for academic purpose, following wikipedia's description.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule

I would like to know, if up to this point it is correct, both from pragmatic programmer and strict cryptographer views.

```
class KeyExpander
{
    private static final int COLUMN_SIZE = 4
    private static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * COLUMN_SIZE

    private final KeyScheduler keyScheduler = new KeyScheduler()

    byte[] expand(byte[] key)
    {
        int expandedKeyLength = deductExpandedKeyLength(key.length)
        byte[] expandedKey = new byte[expandedKeyLength]
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, expandedKey, 0, BLOCK_SIZE)

        for(int activeBlock = BLOCK_SIZE; activeBlock < expandedKeyLength; activeBlock += BLOCK_SIZE)
        {
            byte[] core = Arrays.copyOfRange(expandedKey, activeBlock - COLUMN_SIZE, activeBlock)
            byte[] buffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(expandedKey, activeBlock - BLOCK_SIZE, activeBlock)

            int roundNumber = activeBlock / BLOCK_SIZE
            core = keyScheduler.scheduleCore(core, roundNumber)

            for(int activeByte = 0; activeByte < BLOCK_SIZE; activeByte++)
            {
                buffer[activeByte] ^= core[activeByte % COLUMN_SIZE]
                expandedKey[activeBlock + activeByte] = buffer[activeByte]
            }
        }

        expandedKey
    }

    private int deductExpandedKeyLength(int primeKeyLength)
    {
        switch(primeKeyLength)
        {
            case 16: return 176
            case 24: return 208
            case 32: return 240
            default: throw new RuntimeException("Invalid key length " + primeKeyLength)
        }
    }
}
```

Method expand accepts user's key and returns expanded key for all rounds.
I am looking for way to divide further this method, but unfortunately, inner loop requires access to expandedKey, and I think that passing it by value 100-200 times isn't best idea.
My second idea was to extract it to private field, but it would make whole class state-full (now it is stateless).

```
class KeyScheduler
{
    private final SubstitutionBox substitutionBox = new SubstitutionBox()
    private final RoundConstant roundConstant = new RoundConstant()

    byte[] scheduleCore(byte[] column, int round)
    {
        column = rotate(column)
        column = substitute(column)
        column[0] ^= roundConstant.of(round)

        column
    }

    private byte[] rotate(byte[] column)
    {
        [column[1], column[2], column[3], column[0]]
    }

    private byte[] substitute(byte[] column)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            column[i] = substitutionBox.substitute(column[i])
        }

        column
    }
}
```

Code is written in groovy, but I am using strong types (so it's nearly java).

Beside mentioned defects, I am open for other suggestions.

Comment: There are two classes missing: `SubstitutionBox` and `RoundConstant`.

Comment: I have intentionally skipped them - they are just wrappers over simple tables from wikipedia, You can assume they work fine